# Запрос Doctrine::getTable('table1')->find('1')

Tags: symfony, doctrine

`Doctrine::getTable('table1')->find('1')` - этот запрос выполняет выборку из базы данных или из оперативной памяти.
Если из базы данных, то есть ли решение, которое тащит данные из ОЗУ.

Comment: О чем вы вообще? это PHP а не C/C++, какая ОЗУ

Comment: пардон а какая разница PHP или С? ОЗУ некуда не девается)))все данные проходят через ОЗУ , тот же скрипт PHP загружается в память

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно из Базы, чтобы тащила из ОЗу - это скорее всего вам надо запихать свой скрипт в ОЗУ который и будет хранится там, и его потом из оперативки вызывать - но вам это не надо.